# .Net remoting: Reversing the connection

Tags: .net, remoting

Ok so this is the first time I'm playing with .net remoting but seems fun so far.

Creating a server that exposes a remoting object and then consuming it from a client is a piece of cake and works like a charm. (I'm using a TcpChannel btw)

What I wanna do now is reverse the connection.
Currently the server opens a port and listens for the client, the client connects and gets the reference of the object and has fun with it.
The only thing I want changed is that the client will wait for the connection instead of the server.
The object should be still created on the server and used from the client.

Does this make sense to anyone?!
And if so, is this possible?

Comment: FYI, Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF. It might be fun, but it's not often being used for new development.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Remoting, it's useful to agree on the meanings of the terms "server" and "client". The "server" is the machine that's listening for connections. The "client" is the machine that initiates the connection.

Using those definitions, you want the client to initiate the connection and then have the server call methods on a client-created object.

So what you want is:

- The client creates a `MarshalByReferenceObject` that contains the methods the server will call.
- The client initiates a connection with the server and passes that object reference to the server.
- The server stores that object reference, and calls methods on that object as necessary.

All that said, I agree with the comment that says you should use WCF rather than remoting.